# Как программно добавить layout в Activity?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть некий метод для использования `Retrofit`. И я хочу создать такую штуку, что когда идет загрузка данных то в окне видно прогресс бар.

У меня пока что 10 окон. Чтобы в каждом `Layout` не создавать `ProgressBar`.

Я хочу создать 1 `Layout` с `ProgressBarом`. И при загрузке данных добавить в `Context` этот самый `layout`.

Вроде бы получить `View` не проблема, делается это так
`View viewProgress=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.loading_progress,null);`

Для меня проблема это в том, как этот `View` добавить в текущий `Context`.

И как правильно сделать лучше это? В данный момент я лишь думаю поверх текущего `Layout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы будете отображать своё вью с прогрессом поверх основного лейаута, то это ничем не будет отличаться от [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). Который, в свою очередь, объявлен Deprecated в API 26 именно по причине того, что отображать прогрес по верх данных и блокировать другие действия пользователя считается плохим UX.

Гугл как раз рекомендует использовать встроенные в разметку [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Если у вас какая-то сложная составная вью для прогресса и вы не хотите дублировать её в каждом файле лейаута, то можете, объявив её в отдельном xml, включать в разметку в нужном месте с помощью тега [`<include />`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/loading_progress"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если я добавлю include тогда как мне получить доступ этому layout программно. Чтобы когда делаю запрос то layout который в include отображался. Как только запрос закончился то применить invisible к данному layout.

Просто какой смысл показывать пустой экран пользователю, когда во время запроса, должен быть показан ProgressBar. Чтобы пользователь знал что идет загрузка

Comment: В вашем случае include как раз хорошее решение. Обращаться также, как если бы эти вью были просто в лейауте (на самом деле они и так там есть), то есть через `findViewById(R.layout.root)`. Где R.layout.root - id из include лейаута.

Comment: Еще вопрос. Как сделать проверку на то есть ли этот include или его нет. А то Exception могу получить

Comment: Проверяйте найденную вью на null

Comment: Проверил ваш способ не работает. Нельзя получить доступ к layout из include. Максимум что можно так это дать id данному include и использовать include как VIew. Так что не принимаю ваш ответ. К тому жн он ввел меня в заблуждение на создание новой темы. Просто УЖАС!!!!

Comment: Жалко что нельзя минусовать уже данный ответ!

Comment: @EraNewGames Если вы что-то делаете не так, это не значит, что это не работает. Повторюсь, что добавление через include ни чем не отличается от добавления просто вьюшек, в плане получения к ним доступа. В чём конкретно у вас проблема?